# How to stop IK rotation bending Bones or Mesh

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

When I enabled the rotation under IK, the bone with IK constraint was bent 90 degrees. I rotated the empty to fix the bend. Why did it automatically do this?

[image]

Comment: Because it's trying to match the axes of your IK constrained bone to those of the target-- pointing its Y axis, its tail, in the same direction as the empty's Y axis, and it's Z axis in the same direction as the empty's Z axis.

Comment: @Nathan Hi, thanks for your comment. Do you know how to fix it? My temporary solution is to rotate the empty 90 degrees to make objects straight. However, I do not know if this will cause any potential issues in the later rig process. Please advise. I am new to rig characters. Thanks again!

Comment: Rotating the empty is the right solution.  If you want to enable IK rotation, that is; however, I don't recommend using IK rotation.

Comment: @Nathan May I know why it is not a good idea to use IK rotation? What is your suggestion?

Comment: I don't think that's a question I can address in comments, and this particular question isn't about that-- you might consider asking a new question for that.  I would ask a question like, "I want this behavior from my armature.  Is rotation IK a good solution?  What other solutions exist to this problem, and what are the benefits/drawbacks?"  It's not that enabling rotation is useless, it's just usually not a good idea, for the things many people want it to do.